# How do I know if a color image has color separation?

Tags: image-processing, file-upload, colors, color-profile, color-management

I am using a content creation website. This website only allows me to upload a jpg or tiff image as a cover picture for my content. Furthermore, the uploaded image must have an RGB color profile and must not have color separation.

So, I need to know how to check if a colored JPG image has color separation or not. If it does have color separation, how to remove the color separation? Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is not about programming, so it is off-topic here. Personally I have no idea, but I assume you can upload nearly any JPEG (but if you known what you are doing, so creating a different image). Let's the site to do the validation. I assume they do not want to confuse users by telling them is should be "RGB colour profile" (possibly missing a s so really sRGB), but without storing the data as RGB. Yeah, usually (nearly always) JPEG images do not store data as RGB data (so 3 hues, so hue separation).

Comment: what does "color separation" mean in your situation?

Comment: The information available to you will also depend on the programming-language/libraries available to you. If you are using a third-party content creation website, you may be limited in the technologies you can use.